# Runnable is not being executed completely after the delay is over from Handler's postDelayed() in Oppo F1

Tags: android, kotlin, runnable, android-handler

The logcat shows the following error when run application in oppo f1 version 5.1:

```
ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long 

Blocked msg = { when=-15s421ms what=0 target=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler callback=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver } , cost  = 15162 ms
 >>>Current msg List is:
    Current msg <1>  = { when=-15s412ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <2>  = { when=-15s410ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <3>  = { when=-15s408ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <4>  = { when=-15s405ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <5>  = { when=-15s403ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <6>  = { when=-15s400ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <7>  = { when=-15s398ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <8>  = { when=-15s395ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <9>  = { when=-15s393ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <10>  = { when=-15s386ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <11>  = { when=-15s383ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <12>  = { when=-15s377ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <13>  = { when=-15s374ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <14>  = { when=-15s367ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <15>  = { when=-15s359ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <16>  = { when=-15s350ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <17>  = { when=-15s346ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <18>  = { when=-15s339ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <19>  = { when=-15s336ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    Current msg <20>  = { when=-15s333ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
    >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
07-19 16:36:51.656 12279-12279/com.symphonyfintech.xts E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
    Blocked msg = { when=-4s18ms what=0 target=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler callback=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver } , cost  = 3789 ms
    >>>Current msg List is:
    Current msg <1>  = { when=-3s315ms what=0 target=android.widget.Editor$Blink callback=android.widget.Editor$Blink }
    >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
```

Comment: any solution for this ?

Comment: Any solution i am getting the same error after lunching camera and click image app got crashed with the same error.

Answer (score -2):

> Use Handler with application's main looper.

For reference find code snippet below :

```
val mainHandler = Handler(getMainLooper())
var runnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        //Do your work here !!
    }
}

mainHandler.postDelayed(runnable, //delay)
```